# change source code display path

Tags: html, wordpress

Is there a way to change the pathname in the source code (browsers)?

```
http://my.domain.com/pathname/cms/wp-content/themes/themename/example/example.js
```

to like `http:////my.domain.com/pathname/example/example.js`

i just dont like when people can view the full path directory

when you use `<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>` or `<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>`
full path are automatically added...

any suggestion how to hide this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set up an `.htaccess` rule, something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^pathname/example/(.*)$ pathname/cms/wp-content/themes/themename/$1 [NC,L]
```

You'd then, of course, still have to edit the paths to the files in your template, though.